# Solr how to boost results by giving weightage to few fields

Tags: solr, solr4

I have few fields in solr like fieldPercentage1=13, fieldPercentage2=34 etc for each document. The range of these fields is from 0 to 100. They are the percentages. So, my question is how to boost my query results in solr with these fields.

Basically if there are 2 documents with first document having fieldPercentage1=13,fieldPercentage2=23 and second document having fieldPercentage1=20,fieldPercentage2=25. In my search result I want second document to be ranked morethan the first document as the values of these fields are more . The purpose of these fields is just to boost the documents and thereby helping them to surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options is this:

```
q={!boost b=sum(fieldPercentage1, fieldPercentage2)}text:mysearchhterm
```

More information here:https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ and the functions are here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Also, if you use dismax/edismas, then you can user bf/boost [parameters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#bf_.28Boost_Function.2C_additive.29)

Comment: Can we sort on those two fields. How different would be the result be with sort versus using boost as above?

Comment: yes, you can: sort=sum(fieldPercentage1, fieldPercentage2)+desc